# Sending packet through linux macvtap interface

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tunnel, libvirt

Linux supports an interface type, macvtap. I can't find great documentation on it, but this is a good starter: http://virt.kernelnewbies.org/MacVTap

I'm trying to use this to create a new virtual net device that I can programmatically read and write to for sending raw packets. While I can read from the tap interface fine, I can't figure out any way to write to it.

1. I'm opening the tap device with a regular `open` syscall.
2. Tried using `write` to send a packet, but I get an `Invalid argument (EINVAL)` error response.
3. Also tried to use `sendmsg` but of course get an error that I have a plain file descriptor, not a socket.

Can this be done? Or do macvtap interfaces only support reading from the tap interface and require you use raw sockets or something else for sending packets?

(Libvirt code for macvtap is here: https://gitorious.org/libvirt/libvirt/source/63889e0c775010d8d70b71d25340bab995aa83ce:src/util/virmacaddr.c)

Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ran into this too. I read the kernel source code, and it turns out that macvlan has an offload facility for tcp checksum offload and various other things that is on by default, and requires a bunch of metadata about the packet at the beginning of the buffer, before the packet data (not sure if the format is documented). If you disable the IFF_VNET_HDR flag with a TUNSETIFF ioctl, it works like a normal tap device.